# JQuery: Losing Styles after ajax query succes where I am adding data

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css

I have a table which via ajax I get n rows, after success I add to the tbodyo the table. I dont know why I am losing styles

My table is:

```
<table id="Pedidos">
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th>field 1</th>
       <th>field 1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

After to add data In Jquery I have

```
...
function onSuccessOrder(data) {
    jQuery("#Pedidos tbody").empty().append(data);
}
...
PageMethods.OrdenarTabla(1, "DESC", onSuccessOrder);
```

In OrdenarTabla I set data i need:

```
...
string row = @"
<tr>
    <td class=""check"">{0}</td>
    <td>{1}</td>
</tr>";

return row;
...
```

Why Am I losing the styles? what is wrong?

Comment: Have you checked your final markup after ajax call? Is it correct?

Comment: yes it is success and add correctly the data but I the classes I definded for checkers or everything I losed it after add jQuery with append or html

Comment: Where are your styles defined? Are you using a library such as jquery mobile maybe?

Comment: I am using a standard library styles.css where I difine all td, tr and tables styles. I am not using jquery mobile, standard jquery

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution:

```
jQuery("#Pedidos tbody").empty().append(data);
jQuery("#tbPedidos tbody").find('input:checkbox').uniform({ selectAutoWidth: true });
```

Comment: So you had extra plugin and forgot to mention it?

Comment: uniform is used in jqeury standard, I think, what I forgot to tell is in first column I had a standard input checkbox.I only use fancy plugins for popups